# Search for sheets' name if matched condition then copy paste value with format?

Tags: excel, vba

Update: I was able to solve this problem.  I just remembered VBA use * and ? to present the string 'If Sheet.name Like "**CopyA*"'

---

I would like to make a copy special value with original format of the sources of all sheets contains the word: "CopyA" for example "Apple CopyA","Mango CopyA"

I can use the macro record to see how VBA create sheet and copy special like similar example below.

I am having trouble in the searching for sheet name - All examples I found either I must know exact name (same as Macro record) or I have to make a copy of all sheets (loop though all sheet and copy, no matter the name is).

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("Sheet1(2)").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

How can I search for sheet's name? In this case, any sheet that has "CopyA"?

Comment: NCC, if you have solved your own question you should post your answer as a solution and mark it as solved.

Comment: It is not allowed me to post a solution in a time period. I believe 8 hours after the question is posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way :) You can also use `Instr()`. For example

**For all sheets in the workbook, use this**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "CopyA") Then
            '~~ > Your code
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**For ActiveSheet use this**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Name, "CopyA") Then
        '~~ > Your code
    End If
End Sub
```