# Select worksheet with name with specific characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several sheets. In this case I cannot use Index instead of Select because the location of the sheet I am selecting may change in reference to the other sheets. Here is an example

Sheets in my workbook: Final Report, Alpha_A, Beta

I need to populate the B column of "Final Report" with the last character in the "Alpha_A" sheet (in this case, "A"). In that case I am currently using

```
 Sheets("Alpha_A").Select
 Range("B3:B5000").Value = Right(ActiveSheet.Name, 1)
```

However, this is done in several different workbooks, where each one has Final Report and Beta sheets, but the Alpha sheet may have a different character at the end of the name (ex. Alpha_A, Alpha_B, Alpha_C, etc...).

I am looking for a code to select the sheet in the workbook that contains the word "Alpha" so that I do not have the change the code when the last character of the Alpha sheet changes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for sheets' name if matched condition then copy paste value with format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670402/search-for-sheets-name-if-matched-condition-then-copy-paste-value-with-format)

Comment: The answer to that thread is similar to what I'm trying to do, but when I applied the code to my workbook, nothing happened, which has been the same for the other answers for my question. I'm starting to think there's something wrong on my part

Answer (score 1):

If there is only **1** letter following the underscore, then:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Left(Right(s.Name, 7), Len(s.Name) - 1) = "Alpha_" Then
            Sheets("Final Report").Range("B3:B5000").Value = Right(s.Name, 1)
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

*(Note:  `Select` was not required)*
*(If there is possible more than **1** letter following the underscore, a slight mod is required)*

Comment: Is there a worksheet with a name like ***Alpha_A*** in the workbook ???

Comment: Yes I applied it to the workbook that I referred to in my write up

Answer (score 1):

base on the Gary's Student code, according to what I understand, may be~:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(s.Name, "Alpha_") Then
            s.Range("B3:B5000").Value = Right(s.Name, 1):exit sub
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

Comment: this is way better than mine *(+1)*

Comment: Hi @Gary'sStudent it just fun

Comment: Hi @Nima, it will work, but may be we just don't understand what you mean =))

Comment: It seems like it should definitely work. I did change s.Range("B3:B5000").Value to Sheets("Final Report").Range("B3:B5000").Value, as I would need to reference the Final Report sheet. Is that correct?

Comment: The `Exit Sub` should really be on a new line here to be honest.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen for the suggestion. one of my hard-to-quit habits!